# Ubuntu 14.04 MySQL extension has disappeared

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have PHP version 7.0 on my computer. And so far MySQL had worked just fine. But when I opened the local webpage today I got this error:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

I tried to reinstall the MySQL extension by calling this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

... but I got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mysql'
```

Then I called "sudo apt-cache search php7" but the output does not show the "php-7.0-mysql" in the list.

Does anybody know what might have caused this problem and how to get the MySQL back to PHP?

(As the title says, the OS is Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-mysql

Comment: This isn't the answer you're looking for, but I would recommend upgrading the server. Ubuntu 14.04 reached it's end of life about a year ago (april 30, 2019). Running outdated software is one of the common reasons people get hacked.